# Java Using do-while loop

Tags: java, do-while

Using do-while loop, Write a program that will ask for five (5) integer numbers. Determine the highest and lowest value.
Consider the sample output.

Output:

```
Enter 1st number: 5
Enter 2nd number: 10
Enter 3rd number: 2
Enter 4th number: 50
Enter 5th number: 30

The highest value is: 50
The lowest value is: 2
```

I honestly don't know how to answer this since my professor haven't discussed about determining the numbers using a do while loop. So far, here's what I have

Edit:
I ended up with this code but I don't know how to make the 1st 2nd 3rd 4th 5th show up.

```
enter code here

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner inp=new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = 1;
    int i =1;
    int highestNumber=0;
    int lowestNumber=0;
    
    while (i < 5) {
        System.out.println("Enter " + a++ +" number ");
        int numbers = inp.nextInt();
        
    
        if(highestNumber==0) {
            highestNumber = numbers;        
        }else if(numbers>highestNumber) {
            highestNumber=numbers;          
        };
        
        if(lowestNumber==0) {
            lowestNumber = numbers;     
        }else if(numbers<lowestNumber) {
            lowestNumber=numbers;           
        };
        
        System.out.println("The Highest Number is: " + highestNumber);
        System.out.println("The Lowest Number is: " + lowestNumber);
    
    }
}
```

Comment: C'mon - think logical. You need 5 numbers. You should use a do-while. A loop and and  repeatable actions. That is not that difficult. You need to put the input of an Integer into the loop and check if it is the highest or lowest so far. The loop ends after 5 inputs and you can print the highest and the lowest. Ok - now try again.

Comment: check some tutorials like https://www.baeldung.com/java-do-while-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some homework improvements to meet the requirements:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] nums = new String[] {"1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th"};

        try(Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in)) {

            int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            
            int i = 0;
            do{

                System.out.print("Enter " + nums[i] + " number: ");
                int num = inp.nextInt();

                if(num < min) min = num;
                if(num > max) max = num;

            } while(++i < nums.length);

            System.out.println("\nThe highest value is: " + max);
            System.out.println("The lowest value is: " + min);

        } catch(InputMismatchException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do some research before asking a question like this. While-Loops are well documented all over the internet. That said, this should probably work (haven't tested it though):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner inp=new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] numbers = new int[5];
    int i = 0;
    
    while (i < numbers.length) {
        System.out.println("Enter number " + i);
        numbers[i] = inp.nextInt();
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like it includes the highest and lowest numbers in the output.

Comment: @Joe that's left as an exercise to the student. :)